# plotly choropleth according to a number state

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

I want to to build map USA according to number the state How many times it was repeated in data
i try to do choropleth but my problem I don't know what should I write in color
this my code

```
px.choropleth(df, 
          locations = 'state',
          color='... what should i write ....', 
         animation_frame='year',
          color_continuous_scale="Inferno",
          locationmode='USA-states',
          scope="usa",
          range_color=(0, 633),
          title='....',
          height=600
         )
```

and here part of my data
[image]

```
df.head().to_dict()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi saas, please share your data as code not image. You can just add the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: [Using Built-in Country and State Geometries](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) Kindly refer to this. In this example, we have tied the shortened name of the state to the color (number). If you use this number as a frequency, you can draw it.

Comment: hi  @r-beginners  if i use the state for color what should i use for locations i can't use city because it's don't work and if use state for both its just print map

Comment: I can't follow up well with comments alone. We would get better responses from lots of people if we had sample data to present.

Comment: hi @rpanai i added

Comment: @r-beginners what you mean about sample data what should I add

Comment: Please add the output as text/code not image.

Comment: It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

*It might be late ... but might be useful.*

If the number of states is needed to do so you can simply use `value_counts()`

```py
df_count = df[['state', 'year']].value_counts().reset_index()

df_count.columns = ['state', 'year', 'freq']

fig = px.choropleth(
    data_frame=df_count,
    locations='state',
    locationmode="USA-states",
    animation_frame='year',
    color='freq',
    hover_name='state',
    scope="usa"
)
fig.show()
fig.write_html("Count Of States.html")
```